# Keras hypernetwork implementation?

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

What would be the most straightforward way to implement a hypernetwork in Keras?  That is, where one leg of the network creates the weights for another?  In particular, I would like to do template matching where I feed the template in to a CNN leg that generates a convolutional kernel for a leg that operates on the main image.  The part I'm unsure of is where I have a CNN layer that is fed weights externally, yet the gradients still flow through properly for training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The weights leg:

For the weights leg, just create a regiular network as you would with Keras.

Be sure that its output(s) have shape like `(spatial_kernel_size1, spatial_kernel_size2, input_channels, output_channels)`

Usint the functional API you can create a few weights, for instance:

```
inputs = Input((imgSize1, imgSize2, imgChannels))

w1 = Conv2D(desired_channels, ....)(inputs)
w2 = Conv2D(desired_channels2, ....)(inputs or w1)
....
```

You should apply some kind of pooling here, since your outputs will have a huge size and you probably want filters with small sizes such as 3, 5, etc.

```
w1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(w1) #maybe GlobalMaxPooling2D
w2 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(w2)
```

If you're using fixed image sizes, you could also use other kinds of pooling or flatten and dense, etc.

Make sure you reshape the weights for the correct shape.

```
w1 = Reshape((size1,size2,input_channels, output_channels))(w1)
w2 = Reshape((sizeA, sizeB, input_channels2, output_channels2))(w2)
....
```

The choice of the number of channels is up to you to optimize

### The convolutional leg:

Now, this leg will only use "non trainable" convolutions, they can be found directly in the backend and be used in `Lambda` layers:

```
out1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.conv2d(x[0], x[1]))([inputs,w1])
out2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.conv2d(x[0], x[1]))([out1,w2])
```

Now, how you're going to interleave the layers, how many weights, etc., is also something you should optimize for yourself.

Create the model:

```
model = Model(inputs, out2)
```

### Interleaving

You may take an output from this leg as input for the weight generator leg too:

```
w3 = Conv2D(filters, ...)(out2)
w3 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(w3)
w3 = Reshape((sizeI, sizeII, inputC, outputC))(w3)
out3 = Lambda(lambda x: K.conv2d(x[0], x[1]))([out2,w3])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. I'm close right now, but my the conv2d in my lambda layer is angry because the dimensionality of the filter is [?, spatial1, spatial2, channels_in, channels_out] with the "?" being the batch dimension.  It doesn't seem to understand to ignore the batch dimension automatically the way standard layers do.  The result is that internally it thinks I'm in 3D and I get a "list index out of range" error.  Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Hmmm, true.... must think about it.... you want the weights to change for each sample?  The first thing I can think of, very probably not fast, is to have a fixed batch size (create the model with `batch_shape` or `batch_input_shape`, then split the filters in n filters, and then create one conv for each filter for each sample.

Comment: I'm still working it (it builds but haven't tried training), but I ended up making a custom lambda layer that loops over the batch size.  The docs are somewhat unclear, but conv2d() has an implied batch dimension for the input, but not for the filter/kernel.  My custom layer loops over the batch dimension of the filter(s) and concatenates the results back together.  To be clear, my application has batch elements consisting of all three: (template, image, desired result).

Comment: Yes, that was the sugestion. One conv per item in batch (weird, non optimal, but it seems it's the only I can see)